# How to implement a two factor authentication using smart cards and smart card readers via web

Tags: php, web, smartcard, smartcard-reader, two-factor-authentication

First of all, please excuse my ignorance about this topic. ([related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_Authentication_Program))

What exactly is needed to implement a process like this:

1. Client visits login site (example.com/login).
2. To login, the client enters its client ID. Also, a random (?) code is
   displayed to the visitor:
   **251 221 555**.
3. The client picks up his *smart card reader*, puts his smart card into it and clicks on the "Login" button, enters the code **251 221 555**
4. The client then enter his PIN code (in the smart card reader)
5. A token is then returned: **922 444 113**
6. The client uses the returned token to login in the website.

I guess one needs:

- A smart card (which has a PIN code)
- A smart card reader ([see picture 1](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid/img/gempcpinpad.png), [2](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Barclays_Pinsentry_5920.jpg/800px-Barclays_Pinsentry_5920.jpg))

What I wonder is how to authenticate the returned token in a website, and also how to return a token in the smart card reader?
What are the exact (or simplest) steps to implement a process like the one above?

Comment: Have you considered using a client certificate stored on smartcard? It should be possible even with a secure pin entry device and might be much simpler to implement (but requires the reader to be connected to the computer, some drivers/middleware installed etc. -- depends on your use-case and the actual components used). For the challenge-response method it is not clear (for me) whether you want to actually use the CAP or not (as it might be quite difficult to get standalone /i.e. not PC-connected/ reader supporting some other protocol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest implementation is to have a secret key stored in the smartcard, and trigger an encryption or MAC calculation over the input number. For this to work PIN entry should be **before** input number.

The commands would be

- VERIFY (with the PIN)
- INTERNAL AUTHENTICATE (with the input number)
- or PERFORM SECURITY OPERATION in mode Compute Cryptographic Checksum.

For more details you should have a detailed look into ISO 7816 part 4 (verify and internal auth.) and 7816 part 8 (perform security op.). This assumes a so-called native card (as opposed to a JavaCard).

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need a smart card (EMV) reader and a similar card like SLE4442 smart card. Are all EMV readers out there for instance working with Arduino? What smart card reader would you recommend for Arduino?

Comment: @Kilise: Sorry, I have no experience with smart card readers in embedded environment; take one, where you can find appropriate drivers. SLE4442 being a (synchronous) memory card is far too dumb to support the mentioned commands. You need an asynchronous processor card.